# Create pdf file from multiple models in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, prawn, html-to-pdf

In my rails app the user inputs a lot of data in different models. The user should have the possibility to create a pdf file from all the data he inputted in the different models. Which ruby gem does provide this functionality and how can it be used? I already looked into Prawn but couldn‘t figure out, if it provides the functionality to create one pdf with data from different models.

Comment: you can use Prawn to generate pdf that data sources from  many models, the key is how you relate your models and access it's data through active record, image prawn just like views

Comment: Try wkhtmltopdf

Comment: @widjajayd I saw that is possible to generate a pdf from one model. E.g I have a model called deadlines I would create a class DeadlinesPdf where I could pass the deadlines variable from the deadlines controller with all deadlines stored in it and show the values in the pdf. But if I have a second model called tasks that should be shown in the same pdf, how can this be done? Because in the controller I say: format.pdf do { pdf = PdfName.new(@deadlines, view_context) ... }. So I would create a new pdf in each controller. But the data should go in the same pdf.

Comment: @MDTawabAlamKhan As I understood, for wkhtmltopdf I need to have a html site with all my data from all my models. As there should be about 15 models rendered and converted into a pdf, I fear that this could have a very poor performance. The generated pdf would have about 60 to 100 sites with a lot of images. What do you think?

Comment: @widjajayd here is the link to the example I found to create a pdf from one model: https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/14560/advanced-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here sort tutorial how to use prawn pdf to print related models

for example I have parent model and it has many cars (related model)

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars, allow_destroy: :true
end
```

inside my controller I defined as follow

```
class ParentsController < ApplicationController

  def show
      @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html     
        format.pdf do
            # here you call prawn pdf class (see below)
            pdf = ParentPdf.new(@parent)
            send_data pdf.render, filename: 'family.pdf',
                                  type: 'application/pdf',
                                  disposition: 'inline'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

you can create folder and file as follow app/pdf/parent_pdf.rb and it inherit from Prawn::Document class

```
class ParentPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(parent)
    # init margin and size
    super(top_margin: 5, left_margin: 5, page_size: 'A4', page_layout: :landscape, print_scaling: :none)

    # pass argument to variable
    @parent = parent
    # here is you access related models like you access from your controller
    @cars = @parent.cars
    # you print the model
    print_header 
    # and print related model
    print_detail
  end 

  def print_header
    bounding_box([420, 510], width: 350, height: 90) do
      text "name: #{@parent.name}", size: 11
    end
  end

  def print_detail
    font 'Helvetica'
    font_size 9
    @cars.each do |car|
      text "car: #{car.name}", size: 11
    end
  end

end
```

and last is the command to print the pdf through hyper link

```
<%= link_to 'print pdf', parent_path(parent, format: "pdf"), :class => 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary' %>
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, because all my models belong to the model called project. I will give this a try! Trank you (y)

Comment: Worked as intended! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Prawn is a library for generating PDFs from *any* data. How you create the PDF is up to you. And also where your data comes from. So have a look at the documentation from Prawn on how to do things.

You might also want to check out `prawn-table` since it provides support for adding tables to a PDF document.

I don't think that you will find any pre-built solution for what you want to do.

Comment: I already looked into the documentation and tutorials. But I only found information about how to create a pdf from one model. Here is the resource: https://riptutorial.com/ruby-on-rails/example/14560/advanced-example. Do you have an idea about how to do this for multiple models? The problem I have is, that in every controller a new pdf is created, where as I want them to use the same pdf to pass their instance variable to.